# Projector Selection

Tags: projector

What should I look at when selecting a projector? (technology wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price of lamps is a big one. If you figure that your lamp might last a year, you won't want to get one that is going to be expensive.

I find that the contrast level is useful, showing the difference between white and black. I think it's a better indication of brightness than the "Lumens" metric.

I have a Dell projector as my TV at home, and it's generally fine. I've had it for over a year, and because I have kids it's on a lot of the time. The brightness of the lamp has dimmed somewhat, but it's still a very nice option in what is essentially a darkish room.